# Understanding the proof of Galois theory

Tags: galois-theory

I'm reading Fraleigh's Abstract Algebra, but I cannot understand the argument in the this book in page 453, Main Theorem of Galois Theory. The following is what he says.

Suppose $K$ is normal extension of $F$, and $E$ is an intermediate field between $F$ and $K$. Then $E$ is a normal extension of $F$ iff $G(K/E)$ is a normal subgroup of $G(K/F)$.

Since $K$ is separable over $F$, $E$ is also separable extension of $F$. Thus $E$ is normal over $F$ iff E is a splitting field over $F$. By the Isomorphism Extension Theorem, every isomorphism of $E$ onto a subfield of $F^*$, where $F^*$ is algebraically closed field containing $F$, leaving $F$ fixed can be extended to an automorphism of $K$, since $K$ is normal over $F$. Thus the automorphisms of $G(K/F)$ induce all possible isomorphisms of $E$ onto a subfield of $F^*$ leaving $F$ fixed. **This shows that $E$ is a splitting field over $F$, and hence is normal over $F$, iff for all $\sigma \in G(K/F)$ and $\alpha \in E$, $\sigma (\alpha) \in E$.**

I understood the only if part, but cannot understand why the if part is also true. To prove that $E$ is a splitting field over $F$, we have to show that every isomorphism $\sigma$ on $E$ leaving $F$ fixed is automorphism on $E$. But the right part of proposition just say that $\sigma (E) \subset E$. We need to show that $\sigma(E) = E$ to be automorphism on $E$, but I cannot check this part. Any help?

Comment: Replace $E$ by $\sigma(E)$ and $\sigma$ by $\sigma^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank  you very much!! I understand that :)